# How to write select query to fetch data from 5 tables using foreign Key & joins in php MySQL?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have created 6 tables. I want to fetch particular id data's from the all 6 tables(A,B,C,D,E,F) using foreign key. I tried to fetch data individually. It is working fine. I can able to combine 2 tables. But how to combine 6 Tables and write single query to fetch the data(using join).

```js
<?php
include 'db.php';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
 $email=$_POST['email'];
  echo $email;

 $sql="SELECT * FROM A WHERE emailaddress='$email'";
 $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    if($result->num_rows>0){
      while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $email=$row['emailaddress'];
        $user_id=$row['id'];
        echo '<br>';
      }
    }

  $sql1="SELECT groupid FROM C WHERE userid='$user_id'";
 $result1=mysqli_query($conn,$sql1);
    if($result1->num_rows>0){
      while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)){
        $groupid=$row['groupid'];
        echo 'group id'.$groupid;
        echo '<br>';
      }
  }

  $sql2="SELECT policy_id FROM E WHERE groupid='$groupid'";
  $result2=mysqli_query($conn,$sql2);
    if($result2->num_rows>0){
      while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)){
        $policyid=$row['policy_id'];
        echo 'policyid'.$policyid;
        echo '<br>';
      }
  }

  $sql3="SELECT page_id FROM F WHERE policyid='$policyid'";
  $result3=mysqli_query($conn,$sql3);
    if($result3->num_rows>0){
      while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3)){
        $pageid=$row['page_id'];
        echo 'page id'.$pageid;
        echo '<br>';
      }
  }

}

 ?>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="" method="POST">
 <input type="text" name="email">
 <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I will give one email ID.On clicking submit I need to get all the related data from 6 table using single select query.

[image]

Comment: Use Inner Join.

Comment: Is there any answer is helpful to you. Make sure accept it to help other visiter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this query :

```
$sql =  "SELECT * FROM A INNER JOIN C ON A.id = C.userid INNER JOIN ON B ON B.id = C.groupid INNER JOIN E ON E.groupid = B.id INNER JOIN D ON D.policy_id = E.policy_id INNER JOIN F ON F.policyid = D.policy_id WHERE emailaddress = '$email' ";
```

Comment: Thanks rawathemant. It was helpful.I am trying to insert the query in my coding.

Answer (score 1):

Need to use **inner join** to combine all tables shown in image. I've created a query based on relation in image:

```
SELECT * FROM A INNER JOIN C ON C.userid = A.id INNER JOIN B ON B.id = C.groupid INNER JOIN E ON E.groupid = B.id INNER JOIN D ON D.policy_id = E.policy_id INNER JOIN F ON F.policyid = D.policy_id WHERE A.emailaddress='$email'
```